# Unable to resize the blob/image before setting it to document property for the use in a text area

Tags: python, ironpython, spotfire

I am trying to reload an image in a loop from the blob's URL into a text area.

So, I am following the given IronPython examples to be able to download a blob and set to a document property called Img1 and eventually I'm setting that property to a label inside the text area. And my plan is to run this in a wait-loop cycle.

The code looks like this:

```
#from System.Drawing import Image
from System import Uri 
from System.Net import HttpWebRequest
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data  import BinaryLargeObject

uri = Uri("http://100.206.214.99/remote/display.bmp")
request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri)
response = request.GetResponse()
stream = response.GetResponseStream()
blob = BinaryLargeObject.Create(stream)
Document.Properties["Img1"] = blob
```

It's all working fine, but I'm not able to adjust the height or width of the image/blob. Can anyone help me with this?